# AWS Amplify Social login using Auth.federatedSignIn()

Tags: authentication, aws-amplify, capacitor

I'm trying to authenticate a user via social login, but it gives me an error.

`POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 ERROR NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool. ERROR NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool.`
Already added google identity provider in congnito.

Code:

```
import { GoogleAuth } from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';

async googleAuth() {
      let googleUser = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
      const token = googleUser.authentication.idToken;
      let user = {
        email: googleUser.email,
        name: googleUser.name,
      };
      const expiresIn = 3600;
      const providerName = 'google';

      try {
        await Auth.federatedSignIn(
          providerName,
          {
            token,
            expires_at: expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime(),
          },
          user,
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Ensure that, Your google app id should be same in cognito provider and in your code should be match.

Comment: Yes, I checked the app ID, and it's all good. But it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Google"  instead "google" for the providerName.

I noticed that the enum is capitalized in `CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google`